# nextJs build error Export encountered errors on following paths how to fix?

Tags: build, next.js13, app-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLuXo.png)

An error like the picture occurs while building nextjs.

There was no problem when I ran yarn dev on the local host, but an error occurred when I ran yarn build.

As an example, I will write down one of the problematic components.

```
import BreadCrumb from '@/components/BreadCrumb';
import FavoriteAssetList from '@/components/FavoriteAssetList/FavoriteAssetList';
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import React from 'react';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: `Favorite`,
  description: 'Favorite',
};

export default async function page() {
  return (
    <>
      <BreadCrumb breadCrumbArray={BREADCRUMB_LIST} />
      <FavoriteAssetList />
    </>
  );
}

const BREADCRUMB_LIST = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    link: '/',
  },
  {
    name: 'Favorite',
    link: '/favorite',
  },
];
```

I tried to resolve the error by researching, but failed.